# mysql show user who create database

Tags: mysql

I have a database named `test1` for which every user can see and use it. When fire up `show databases()` command in terminal I always see that database in the result.

I'm not sure which user has created that database. Could you show me a command to display user name or else could you explain to me what happens with `test1` database?

Comment: without any further information, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: I created 'test1' database before. And login as any user (event with user who logs onto mysql by typing only 'mysql' command), that user can still see and use that 'test1' database besides the default 'test' database in mysql. I typed in 'showdatabase()' command and it always shows me 'test1' database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> upon installation of MySQL 5.0+, mysql.db is populated with two
>   entries that allow test databases to be accessed by anonymous users.

Installation of mysql 5.0+ version is already coming with test database that allow anonymous users.

@RolandoMySQLDBA already brought this issue in https://dba.stackexchange.com/ ... Have a look onto [MySQL : Why are there “test” entries in mysql.db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mysql-why-are-there-test-entries-in-mysql-db) .

Possible solution are either you can do mysql installations using [mysql_secure_installation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-secure-installation.html) 
or it is advisable to drop the unwanted default databases and delete anonymous users. 
Please have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/default-privileges.html).

It would be nice to have a read on [MySQL Security Best Practices](http://www.greensql.com/content/mysql-security-best-practices-hardening-mysql-tips)

Comment: I already marked your answer as accepted one. However, it would be great if you could tell me how to create a database that are available for every user on the system?

Comment: For that better you add a user having privileges in all tables in all databases. Consider following links for references : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql , http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html ,